# Programmatically create MSTest unit tests

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mstest, vs-unit-testing-framework

I am looking for a way to programmatically create unit tests using MSTest.  I would like to loop through a series of configuration data and create tests dynamically based on the information.  The configuration data will not be available at compile time and may come from an external data source such as a database or an XML file.  Scenario:  Load configuration data into a test harness and loop through the data while creating a new test for each element.  Would like each dynamically created test to be reported (success/fail) on separately.

Comment: Why not just use the data driven testing capabilities built into MSTest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Data Driven Testing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527.aspx) depending on how complex your data is.  If you are just substituting values and testing to make sure that your code can handle the same inputs that might be the way to go, but this doesn't really sound like what you are after.  (You could make this more complex, after all all you are doing is pulling in values from a data source and then making a programmatic decision based on it)

All MS Test really does is run a series of tests and then produce the results (in an xml file) which is then interpreted by the calling application.  It's just a wrapper for executing methods that you designate through attributes.

What it sounds like you're asking is to write C# code dynamically, and have it execute in the harness.
If you really want to run this through MS test you could:

1. Build a method (or series of methods) which looks at the XML file
2. Write out the C# code (I would maybe look at T4 Templates for this) (Personally, I would use F# to do this, but I'm more partial to functional languages, and this would be easier for me).
3. Calls the csc.exe (C# compiler)
4. Invokes MS Test

You could also write MSIL code into the [running application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463508/NET-CLR-Injection-Modify-IL-Code-during-Run-time) directly, and try to get MS Test to execute it, which for some might be fun, but that could be time consuming and not necessarily guaranteed to work (I haven't tried it, so I don't know what the pit falls would be).

Based on this, it might be easier to quickly build your own harness which will interpret your XML file and dynamically build out your test scenarios and produce the same results file.  (After all the results are what's important, not how you got there.) Since you said it won't be available during compile time, I would guess that you aren't interested in viewing the results in the VS studio window.

Actually, personally, I wouldn't use XML as your Domain Specific Language (DSL).  The parsing of it is easy, because .NET already does that for you, but it's limiting in how it would define how your method can function.  It's meant for conveying data, and although technically code is a form of data, it doesn't have the sufficient expressive strength to convey many abilities in more formal language. This is just my personal opinion though, and there are many ways to skin a cat.